# Facebook Swift SDK: Using App Access Token

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

In my app I want to make calls with my App Access Token to public events. How can I set the current AccessToken to my App Access Token? It seems that Facebook sets the AccessToken automatically when logging in, but I cannot find where I can set a token manually.

I'm trying to make the graph work in this way:

```
struct MyProfileRequest: GraphRequestProtocol {
    var accessToken: AccessToken? = AccessToken(authenticationToken: "XXX")
    // Assume my App Access Token works, as it does in the Token Tool. Token got from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

    var parameters: [String : Any]?

    struct Response: GraphResponseProtocol {
        init(rawResponse: Any?) {
            // Decode JSON from rawResponse into other properties here.
        }
    }

    var graphPath = "/562230910790496"
    var httpMethod: GraphRequestHTTPMethod = .GET
    var apiVersion: GraphAPIVersion = .defaultVersion
}

... // Somewhere in a ViewController

let connection = GraphRequestConnection()
connection.add(MyProfileRequest()) { httpResponse, result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let response):
        print("Graph Request Succeeded: \(response)")
    case .failed(let error):
        print("Graph Request Failed: \(error)")
    }
}
connection.start()
```

Comment: You are not putting the App Access token in something the user have access to right? You are not putting it in an app that the user is downloading?

Comment: For now I am, this is for testing purposes. Is that why it can’t be done?

Comment: Why would you do it for testing purposes? Just use the right access token

Comment: You should really not be using an app access token in client-side code - everyone could steal it from there, and then act as your app. In client-side code, you should be using the user’s access token as much as possible.